# How to convert HTML to Docx and PDF with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, converters, docx

I want to be able to convert RichText HTML, output that I'll be able to get from an editor like TinyMCE or CKEditor and convert it to Docx and PDF with formatting intact. I tried to search up other methods but they use PHP, are online apps or desktop apps. I need to be able to convert it with JavaScript.

**UPDATE**
Since I couldn't find any solution that purely uses JS to convert documents, I used Unoconv instead. This allows me to convert a wide array of file types into HTML or any other file type.

Comment: Did you try this one? https://www.npmjs.org/package/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Thank you! I actually found something else that pretty nice as well. It's called CloudConvert. Not free but it works!

Comment: You could also try GrabzIt's DOCX API, it supports node.js and plain JavaScript: https://grabz.it/html-to-word-docx-api.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this for PDF creation: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf.

I've never done DocX creation, but this looks promising and I'd give it a shot: http://blog.innovatejs.com/?p=184.

FYI the package mentioned by MikeNQ above is only for Webkit, whereas jsPDF is cross-browser.

Comment: Another thing that you can check out if your interested. It's called CloudConvert. It's a nice platform.

Comment: The docx.js version on innovatejs is only allowed to be used if all your visitors are only using Microsoft Windows on PC so if someone enters your site on an Android your in violation of the license. Also, the site is marked as dangerous/infected.